# .net c # : Creating a Async Process

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am creating a Console Application, in that I need to Call a Method, that will do a list of JOBS.
But I want that Method does not have any impact on Main Application, It will just do it's jobs.. that's all.

Comment: And what do those JOBS look like? Any shared data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts553s52(VS.80).aspx).

Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class ServerClass
{
    // The method that will be called when the thread is started.
    public void InstanceMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "ServerClass.InstanceMethod is running on another thread.");

        // Pause for a moment to provide a delay to make 
        // threads more apparent.
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "The instance method called by the worker thread has ended.");
    }

    public static void StaticMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "ServerClass.StaticMethod is running on another thread.");

        // Pause for a moment to provide a delay to make 
        // threads more apparent.
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "The static method called by the worker thread has ended.");
    }
}

public class Simple{
    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread Simple Sample");

        ServerClass serverObject = new ServerClass();

        // Create the thread object, passing in the 
        // serverObject.InstanceMethod method using a 
        // ThreadStart delegate.
        Thread InstanceCaller = new Thread(
            new ThreadStart(serverObject.InstanceMethod));

        // Start the thread.
        InstanceCaller.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("The Main() thread calls this after " 
            + "starting the new InstanceCaller thread.");

        // Create the thread object, passing in the 
        // serverObject.StaticMethod method using a 
        // ThreadStart delegate.
        Thread StaticCaller = new Thread(
            new ThreadStart(ServerClass.StaticMethod));

        // Start the thread.
        StaticCaller.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("The Main() thread calls this after "
            + "starting the new StaticCaller thread.");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- [Asynchronous Programming
  Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(VS.71).aspx)
- [Multi-threading in .NET:
  Introduction and suggestions](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/)